# Is there anyway to remove, neutralize or deactivate phytic acid in whole wheat pasta?

Tags: nutrient-composition

I bought a bunch of packs of whole wheat pasta thinking how nutritious this would be and now I read the very thing I am after which are the minerals in the hardened shell of the grain also contain phytic acid which blocks absorption in the intestine.

A perfect example of nature telling me, you can't have your cake and eat it too. I might be able to squeeze by with this question since technically phytic acid is a micronutrient and has some benefits. I know boiling removes very little and I am wondering if anyone has found a novel way to get rid of the phytic acid?

Comment: @bob1 I feel like it's a legitimate question even if the most useful answer is "there is no reason to do this".

Comment: If this drifts off towards a discussion about nutrition, it’s off topic ( take that to chat, if you like). Sticking purely to the measurable quantities of one item is fine.

Comment: Per NIH study, the nutrient-blocking properties of phytic acid are exaggerated: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/10655952/

Comment: @FuzzyChef Nice article ... one would think it would have been just the opposite.

Comment: After doing a little more research. I read milling removes phytic acid. All purpose flour is milled. I also read semolina is milled....but google has semolina containing phytic acid. Which is contradictory. My question is mute since there is no way to remove it after manufacture .

Comment: Easy solution: toss the whole wheat and get normal.  I mean if you actually like eating then sure but most people find it to taste like garbage, it will throw off any recipe, and to be frank the health benefits of whole wheat pasta and rice are very minimal and easily replaceable by other sources.

Comment: 'mute' and 'moot' have different meanings.

Comment: @eps. That will be my solution. But I will gift the whole wheat to my neighbor, he likes whole wheat. In fact I just went to the store today and bought some good old fashined pasta, problem fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no

If you are willing to make your own whole wheat pasta then sprouting the wheatberries first reduces phytic acid.